# No ClassCastException on wrong generic cast [Java]

Tags: java, generics, casting, classcastexception, raw-types

Have a look at the main method of the following class:

```
public class Outer {
    static class A<T> {
        public A<T> a;
        public T t;

        public A() { a = null; }
        public A(T t) {
            a = (A<T>) new B();
            a.t = t;
        }
    }

    static class B extends A<Integer> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A<String> c = new B();              // CREATION 1: would not work
        // A<String> b = (A<String>) new B();  // CREATION 2: would not work
        A<String> a1 = new A<>("str");         // CREATION 3: works (???)
        A<String> a2 = new A(0);               // CREATION 4: works (???)

        System.out.println(a1.a);    // CALL 1 -> Poly$B@...
        System.out.println(a1.t);    // CALL 2 -> null
        System.out.println(a1.a.a);  // CALL 3 -> null
        System.out.println(a1.a.t);  // CALL 4 -> str (???)
        System.out.println(a2.a.t);  // CALL 5 -> ClassCastException (???)
    }
}
```

---

Obviously, creation 1 and 2 would fail at compile time, since the cast cannot be possible. The 3rd object creation could be possible, so I did not expect it to fail at compile time, but: I expected `(A<T>) new B();` to fail at runtime, since `B` extends `A<Integer>` and it should not be possible to cast `A<Integer>` to `A<String>` (same as creation 2)... But there is no ClassCastException here!?

Unfortunately, creation 3 works. `a1.a.t` (which is the `t` member of a `B` object) will now store the String "str"!? So a `B` object (meaning `t` is of type `Integer`) can store `String`s in `Integer t`!!?

Another thing: Look at `a2`. Trying to access `a2.a.t` will produce a ClassCastException. This surprises me, since there is not even a cast performed during the access - at least, this is what I thought...

So my questions in short are:

1. **Why is creation 3 (/4) possible?**
2. **Why is a B object able to store a String in its generic Integer variable t?**
3. **Why does call 5 fail at runtime?**

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is creation 3 (/4) possible?**

Creation 3 Is the "diamond" syntax for inferring type. So `new A<>` is the same as writing `new A<String>`.

So we can replace that with the long, pre-Java 1.7 syntax.

```
A<String> a1 = new A<String>("str");
```

This will go through the following constructor, where `T` was `java.lang.String` and `t` is a `java.lang.String`. Note, there is just one copy of this code at runtime, with the raw type of `T` being `java.lang.Object`.

```
    public A(T t) {
        a = (A<T>) new B();
        //  ^^^^^^ NB: This will at least give a rawtype warning
        //             as it causes heap pollution.
        a.t = t;
    }
```

The type of `a` is `A<T>` at compile time and `java.lang.Object` erased. The type of both `a.t` and `t` is `T` at compile time and `java.lang.Object` erased. So it compiles without warning and there is no casting to check at runtime. The assignment succeeds.

Creation 4 is using raw types. Your compiler should give a warning (use `-Xlint`). Ignoring these warning may lead to `ClassCastException` later on. Generics are a compiler "fiction" over the real virtual machine, which essentially follows the rules of the Java 1.0 language.

**Why is a B object able to store a String in its generic Integer variable t?**

The erased type of `t` in `A` (and hence `B`) is `java.lang.Object` and can therefore store any reference type if there is no or incorrect checking.

**Why does call 5 fail at runtime?**

The object at `a2.a.t` is a `java.lang.Integer`. `a2.a` has static type `A<java.lang.String>` so the static type of `a2.a.t` is `java.lang.String`. `javac` will insert a cast in order to check that the raw type returned conforms to the static type. In this particular case, IIRC, older versions of `javac` would incorrect omit the cast and use the `println(java.lang.Object)` overload instead of `println(java.lang.String)`.

You can use `javap -c -private` to see exactly where `checkcast` instructions are placed.

**Conclusion**

Make sure you have warnings switched on. Anything which doesn't have them on by default is somewhat suspect. Don't ignore or suppress warnings, particularly about raw types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still don't understand, why creation 3 is possible. It's not about the diamond operator. **A<String> c = (A<String>) new B();** would not work, but the same happens with creation 3 (see constructor of A): **a = (A<T>) new B();** where T is String (creation 3), should do **a = (A<String>) new B();**. Why is it possible to cast B (A<Integer>) to A<String>?

Comment: @stecrz I've added a bit more detail. Normally a cast from `A<Integer>` to `A<String>` would fail. You'd have to go via the raw type. `(A<String>)(A)new B()`. It seems as `B` is not a generic type itself the cast is allowed (with an important warning).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have warning switched on, but still didn't understand the background, that's why I asked. Thanks for your explanation!