# Why does this unchecked cast NOT cause a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am doing an experiment with generics, and I recently came across this phenomenon. In a constructor for a parameterized class, I am doing an unchecked cast. I know this is bad practice (my IDE also gives me a warning, as it should). In my `main()` method, I am expecting the first line to run successfully and for the second to cause a `ClassCastException` to be thrown. However, this does not happen.

I expect the line `Animal<String> bad = new Animal()` to throw an exception, as `(T) this` in the `Animal` constructor would effectively become `(String) this` where `this` is of type `Animal`; which is of course an invalid cast. However, this does not happen. The program runs successfully and exits.

```
public class Generics {

    public static class Animal<T> {

        private final T value;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Animal() {
            this.value = (T) this;
            System.out.println(value.getClass());
        }

    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {

        public Cat() {
            super(); /* of course, this works */
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat(); /* all good */
        Animal<String> test = new Animal<>();
    }

}
```

Furthermore, printing the value of `value.getClass()` yields an unexpected output:

```
Generics$Cat    /* as expected */
Generics$Animal /* expected a ClassCastException here */
```

I know this is an odd way to use generics, but as I said earlier, this is simply an experiment. I just want to know why this code runs without an exception being thrown. If you need any more information, please let me know in the comments and I will edit the question accordingly. Thank you!

I also realize that this post is similar [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797702/no-classcastexception-on-wrong-generic-cast-java) However, I'm not entirely sure what the author of that question is trying to do there as his code is structured differently from mine.

Comment: `(T) this` doesn't actually become `(String) this`.  It becomes `(Object) this`.  `T` is _erased_ at runtime, it doesn't have any effect on how the program works, only whether or not it compiles.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you @LouisWasserman ! If you post this as the answer to my question, I'll be happy to upvote it and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Louis Wasserman correctly notes that your "cast" to `T` is erased to `Object` at compile-time, but you're on the right track. Instead, however, the cast that fails will be inserted in the code that relies on the generic:

```
public class Animal<T> {
  T value;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public Animal() {
    this.value = (T) this;
  }

  T getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

So far this in itself won't cause an exception, since the physical field type of `value` is `Object`. However, this is where you'll get the `ClassCastException`:

```
void thisFails() {
  Animal<String> animal = new Animal();
  // ^ animal.value is not a String!

  String value = animal.getValue();
  // This is implemented by the compiler as
  // `String value = (String) animal.getValue()`
  // and *this* will fail at runtime with ClassCastException.
}
```

Comment: @Whirvis If you want to dig into how all this works, run `javap -v MyClass.class`. You'll get a complete disassembly of the bytecode, and you can see the actual JVM cast instructions as well as hidden methods that are needed to match up generic and erased method signatures.